# How to connect VPN with Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, cypress, pipeline, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to test a website with Cypress and I can only access to the website with OpenVPN.
When I connect to OpenVPN on my machine, the test works fine with Cypress.
But I need to create a pipeline in Azure Devops for it and schedule it.
Has anyone an idea how to integrate OpenVPN with Azure Devops Pipeline?

I looked for a task to add in the agent job, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to private networks, such as a VPN connection or ExpressRoute is not supported on Microsoft Hosted Azure Devops agents as indicated in [the documentation for Microsoft Hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking)

You could consider running self-hosted agents which you could connect via VPN either in the base configuration of the machine hosting the agent runner or implement the connection as a bash script in your pipeline.

Comment: How can I implement the connection as a bash script in the pipeline?